# Downloading CSV files in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, web-scraping

So I am trying to download stock data using the code below

```
from urllib import request

#Download all daily stock data
for firm in ["SONC"]:
  for year in ["2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"]:
    for month in ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"]:
      # Retrieve the webpage as a string
      response = request.urlopen("https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/"+firm+".csv?trim_start="+year+"-"+month+"-01&trim_end="+year+"-"+month+"-31&collapse=daily")
      csv = response.read()

      # Save the string to a file
      csvstr = str(csv).strip("b'")

      lines = csvstr.split("\\n")
      f = open(""+firm+"_"+year+""+month+".csv", "w")
      for line in lines:
        f.write(line + "\n")
      f.close()
```

But Im running into problems. Namely it onlys works for one iteration (so if I only had one firm, one year, and one month it works) but not for multiple

Below are the error messages I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kdaftari/Desktop/ECON431_Program.py", line 8, in <module>
    response = request.urlopen("https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/"+firm+".csv?trim_start="+year+"-"+month+"-01&trim_end="+year+"-"+month+"-31&collapse=daily")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  It *looks* like it works for me, but I'm only going by the named of the generated files.

Comment: Should I post the errors Im getting?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Please edit them into your question.

Comment: `str(csv).strip("b'")` this is so wrong it hurts. You ought to use `csv.decode('UTF-8')` or similar instead.

Comment: I would be inclined to troubleshoot this by generating the entire list of URLs first; inspecting those visually, then iterating over each with urllib.urlopen() in a try: ... except: ... block ... capturing the list of "bad" URLs but also progressing beyond any bad ones and fetching as many of the CSV files as possible.

I'd also isolate the horrible expression after trim_start= into a separate line and use "%s ...." % (year, month, ...) other string interpolation rather than concatenation.  This is likely to be far more readable and to give you more precise control over the string results.

Comment: So what if the site won't accept invalid dates? You are sending `2009-02-31` as end date, for example.

Comment: it was accepting some but I guess not all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending invalid dates; the server is telling you there is no 31st of February:

```
$ curl -D - -s "http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/SONC.csv?trim_start=2009-02-01&trim_end=2009-02-31&collapse=daily"
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: filename=WIKI-SONC.csv
Content-Type: text/csv
Date: Sat, 07 Mar 2015 22:28:59 GMT
Server: nginx
Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
X-RateLimit-Limit: 50
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 38
X-Request-Id: b5d774b5-e916-40ef-92c4-443ceccf2ba6
X-Runtime: 0.025214
Content-Length: 117
Connection: keep-alive

error
trim_end:You provided 2009-02-31 for trim_end. This is not a recognized date format. Please provide yyyy-mm-dd
```

Note the error message in the body.

You can easily use `datetime.date()` objects to produce proper dates:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

for firm in ["SONC"]:
    for year in range(2009, 2016):
        for month in range(1, 13):
            startdate = date(year, month, 1)
            enddate = date(year + (month // 12), month % 12 + 1, 1) - timedelta(days=1)
            url = 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/{}.csv?trim_start={:%Y-%m-%d}&trim_end={:%Y-%m-%d}&collapse=daily'.format(
                firm, startdate, enddate)
```

Comment: Yea I think that was it, I assumed it worked for a couple (Even when not possible date) so assumed worked for all

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for looking up daily data per month with trim_end stuff

Comment: Also I had one last question, if I wasnt to dowload the csvs into a specific folder on my computer (instead of desktop as it does now), do you know how to do tha

Comment: @Kamster: use the `os.path` module (specifically `os.path.join()`) to prefix your filenames with a specific directory to save files to. Define your paths with forward slashes or use a raw string literal as windows backslashes in paths are also escape sequences in Python strings.

Comment: @Kamster: `dirname = r'C:\Some\path\to\directory'` then build a fikename from there.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to download [this](https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/SONC.csv?trim_start=2009-02-01&trim_end=2009-02-31&collapse=daily) url with `urllib.request`, and web server responses with error `422 Unprocessable Entity`.

Also, if you see on server response, you will see that server described error as:

```
error
trim_end:You provided 2009-02-31 for trim_end. This is not a recognized date format. Please provide yyyy-mm-dd
```

as suggested by Martijn Pieters: 2009-02-31 is incorrect date.

Here I fixed code for you:

```
import calendar
import time
from urllib import request, error as urllib_error

#Download all daily stock data
for firm in ["SONC"]:
    for year in range(2009, 2016): # from 2009 to 2015 inclusive
        for month in range(1, 13):   # from 1 to 12 inclusive
            # Get number of days in month
            days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]

            # Retrieve the webpage as a string
            url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/{firm}.csv" \
                "?trim_start={year}-{month}-01&trim_end={year}-{month}-{days_in_month}" \
                "&collapse=daily".format(
                    firm=firm, year=year, month=month, days_in_month=days_in_month)

            # For easier debugging
            print(url)

            sleep_time = 1
            while True:
                try:
                    response = request.urlopen(url)
                    csv = response.read()
                except urllib_error.HTTPError as ex:
                    if ex.code == 429:  # Too Many Requests
                        print("Server replied with 'Too many requests', sleeping for a second...")
                        time.sleep(sleep_time)

                        # Increase sleep time so that retries doesn't overload server
                        sleep_time = min(2 * sleep_time, 60)

            # Save the string to a file
            file_name = "{firm}_{year}_{month}.csv".format(
                firm=firm, year=year, month=month)
            with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
                f.write(csv)
```

Comment: @Kamster When I'm trying to run this script it at some point fails with `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests`. You need to add some sort of delay between requesting items.

Comment: @Kamster I updated code to handle `Too Many Requests` error, but currently server gives me such error on all requests. I think you should wait for some time, while server will reset it's load counters.

Comment: I think was the problem is I forgot to register for site so needed a key to make more than 50 requests

Comment: Also I had one last question, if I wasnt to dowload the csvs into a specific folder on my computer (instead of desktop as it does now), do you know how to do that

Comment: @Kamster Currently script stores file in *current* directory of running process, so if you will run script from other directory, it will download to other directory. Also you can change `file_name` variable by prepending required directory, like: `file_name = "C:/dir1/dir2/{firm}_{year}...`.